# For 1 billion documents, Populate data from one field to another fields in the same collection using MongoDB

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I need to populate data from one field to multiple fields on the same collection. For example:
Currently I have document like below:

```
 { _id: 1, temp_data: {temp1: [1,2,3], temp2: "foo bar"} }
```

I want to populate into two different fields on the same collection as like below:

```
 { _id: 1, temp1: [1,2,3], temp2: "foo bar" }
```

I have one billion documents to migrate. Please suggest me the efficient way to update all one billion documents?

Comment: yeah, there's no "in the database" way. You'll have to fetch each document, change it in the app and save back.

Comment: Thanks. @SergioTulentsev That was my plan too. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your favorite language, write a tool that runs through all documents, migrates them, and store them in a new database.

Some hints:

- When iterating the results, make sure they are sorted (e.g. on the _id) so you can implement resume should your migration code crash at 90%...
- Do batch inserts: read, say, 1000 items, migrate them, then write 1000 items in a single batch to the new database. Reads are automatically batched.
- Create indexes after the migration, not before. That will be faster and lead to less fragmentation

Answer (score -1):

Here I made a query for you, use following query to migrate your data

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(myDoc) {
    db.collection_new.update(
    {_id: myDoc._id},
    {
        $unset: {'temp_data': 1},
        $set: {
            'temp1': myDoc.temp_data.temp1,
            'temp2': myDoc.temp_data.temp2
        }
    },
    { upsert: true }
    )
});
```

To learn more about foreach cursor please visit [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)

Need **$limit** and **$skip** operator to migrate data in batches. In update query i have used upsert beacuse there if already exist it will update otherwise inserted entry wiil be new.

Thanks

Comment: $limit and $skip? Nope, they are in the aggregation framwork. limit() and skip() are atrociously slow. What does that have to do with batching? Why are you using an upsert for an insert? Why not simply migrate the data in JavaScript? Using $set and $unset requires twice as many writes as doing it right the first time and increases fragmentation.

Comment: `limit` and `skip` for a collection of billions of documents? na-ah, I don't think so :)